# How to get arrow keys and enter key on key pad in Linux to behave like windows7

Tags: python, linux, windows, events, tkinter

I am developing a program to control a machine that will have only a keypad connected. I am using `Python 2.7` and `Tkinter 8.5`. I am using `OptionMenu`s to allow user to do setup on machine.

When I run under Windows I am able to use arrow keys on keypad to traverse thru drop down list, then use key pad enter to pick option. This is not working on Linux (Debian Wheezy).

How do I bind `KP_Enter` to behave as return key?

```
import Tkinter

def c(self, event):
   event.b[".keysym"] = "<<space>>"
   print "button invoked"

t = Tkinter.Tk()

b = Tkinter.OptionMenu(t, ".500", ".510", ".520", 
                       ".550", ".560", ".570", ".580", command=c)
t.bind("<KP_Enter>", c)
e = Tkinter.Entry()
e.pack()
b.pack(anchor=Tkinter.E)

t.mainloop()
```

Comment: have you tried creating a binding to `<KP_Enter>`? Your code only shows a binding on `<Return>`.

Comment: I posted the wrong bit of code, but it dose not work with KP_Enter. I have been studying and am using the following to bind KP_up and KP_down arrows   def focus_next_button(event):
            event.widget.tk_focusNext().focus()
            return("break")
        master.bind("<KP_Down>", focus_next_button)
        def focus_prev_button(event):
            event.widget.tk_focusPrev().focus()
            return("break")
        master.bind("<KP_Up>", focus_prev_button)

Comment: Bryan I think I could work if I knew a way to make tk.focus_next work in drop down list. I am also considering changing the binding in tkinter module , but I am not sure if that is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

With this script (from [here](https://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/keysym)), it should be easy to identify the key event triggered by Tkinter when you press any key, whether that is `<Return>`, `<KP_Enter>`, or (somehow, maybe your keypad has a funny mapping) something else.

Just look at the console output when you press the desired button, and use that key event name in your actual code.

```
import Tkinter

def callback(e):
    print e.keysym

w = Tkinter.Frame(width=512, height=512)
w.bind("<KeyPress>", callback)
w.focus_set()
w.pack()
w.mainloop()
```